# mysql advanced query

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry for my English.
I have a problem with db mysql.
I have a table like this

```
id|rat|time
1 |2  |12:00
2 |0  |12:55
3 |0  |13:05
4 |6  |13:45
5 |0  |14:00
6 |8  |15:00
7 |0  |16:30
8 |9  |17:00
```

I wan't to get rows like that,
id = 2 row there rat=0 and id=4 there rat=6 
i wan't id = 4 row's time minus id=2 row's time
AND

id = 6 row's (rat=8) time  minus id = 5 row's (rat=0) time

We will be table like this

```
id|time
1 |50 minutes
2 |1 hour
3 |30 minutes
```

we will get beetween time  first row  rat=0   until first rat>0

Comment: I can't really understand your data. Are the times start/end times for each rat? What are you trying to get your query to actually do (in human terms)?

Comment: What is it that ties together IDs 2 and 4, 6 and 5?  You saw nothing about how you get a value of 30 minutes for ID = 3.  Is there another column which you aren't showing that is used in the algorithm?